# Meeting point of one falling object and a climbing one

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

We have this red ball, that falls free, with no inicial velocity, off of the top of a building 60 meters high.
A green ball is launched vertically, upwards, with inicial velocity of 20 m/s, after 2 seconds of the red ball launching.

How long does it take for them to meet (in the air, obviously), since the red ball is launched?

I tried to solve this using Newton's Laws of Motion, but my results are not the same of those of the solutions of the book (it gives me 2 seconds and in the book, the solution is 3 seconds, however they don't show us how did they get to that result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red Ball:
$$y_r(t) = 60m -(5m/s^2)t^2$$
After 2 seconds:
$$y_r(2)=60m-20m = 40m,$$
$$v_r(2) = -20m/s.$$
Therefore the  equation of motion of the red ball is (after 2 seconds):
$$y_r(t) = 40m -(20m/s)t-(5m/s^2)t^2.$$
Now the equation of motion of the green ball:
$$y_g(t)=(20m/s)t-(5m/s^2)t^2.$$
They meet when their positions are the same, so:
$$y_r(t)=y_g(t) \Rightarrow 40m -(20m/s)t-(5m/s^2)t^2=(20m/s)t-(5m/s^2)t^2,$$
$$40m=(40m/s)t\Rightarrow t=1s.$$
Therefore the time since the red ball was first thrown is $2s+1s=3s$. I used the approximation of gravity to $10m/s^2$. The coordinate system is an axis ($y$) set perpendicular to the surface of the Earth where the building is, where $0$ is at the ground and $60$ at the top of the building.

Comment: What is the $5m/s^2$? Is that acceleration?

Comment: Yes, it is $\approx \dfrac{g}{2}$.

Comment: Where exactly??

Comment: @VladimirVargas Why did you set the g/2 value as a negative one if the movement equation for a falling body is y=y0+v0t+1/2gt^2 ?

Comment: @MiguelGomes because I chose the ground as the point 0 and above the ground as positive points. g points downwards

Answer (score 0):

Assume: up is positive, $g$ is $-10$ $m/s^2$, $t=0$ when the red ball is tipped over the edge.  Then, using $$s= s_0+v_0t+\frac12 at^2$$:

The height of the red ball, $H_R$ is given by :$$H_R=60-\frac12 \times10 \times t^2=60-5t^2$$The height of the green ball, starting two seconds later $H_G$ is given by:$$H_G=20\times (t-2)-\frac12 \times10 \times(t-2)^2=-60+40t-5t^2$$

Equating these two heights and solving for $t$:$$60-5t^2=-60+40t-5t^2$$ $$t=3.0 \text{ exactly}$$